# Any good music video API?

Tags: api, video, sparql, freebase

**Does anyone know of a good music video API?**

Music video information on *Freebase* is lacking, the *Internet Video Archive's* API returns inconsistent results, and *Yahoo's* YQL Music API has unclear language on what they consider a commercial application.

Comment: What do you need from the API? The video itself, or just the metadata?

Comment: Just the metadata. I'm interested in what music videos artists have been in, though the link to a video itself would be an added bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the API from [EchoNest](http://developer.echonest.com/) -- among other things, it [provides](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/artist.html#video):

> Get a list of video documents found on the web related to an artist.